# concatenating using vue with information from an api

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm wanting take information from an api for example *imdbID* and just add ".html" afterwards so I can then make it a variable I can put inside the href of a button. But I'm stuck on how to do this, thank you in advance.

Here is the js:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    movies: [],
    search: '',
  },
  created() {
    var vm = this
    axios.get('https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Harry+Potter&apikey=a9018efb')
      .then(function(response) {
        vm.movies = response.data.Search
      })
  },
  computed: {
    getMovies() {
      return this.movies.filter(movie => {
        return movie.Title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
      })
    }
  }
})
```

and here is the important bit of HTML:

```
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ movie.Title }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ movie.Year }}</p>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">View Movie</a> //This is where I'm wanting the variable to go
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is something like a `url` property on the `movie` object:

```html
<div class="card-body">
   <h5 class="card-title">{{ movie.Title }}</h5>
   <p class="card-text">{{ movie.Year }}</p>
   <p class="card-text"></p>
   <a :href="movie.url + '.html'" class="btn btn-primary">View Movie</a>
</div>
```

`:href` is shorthand for `v-bind:href`.  This creates a binding to the attribute, which is treated as a reactive JavaScript expression

Comment: I'm trying to add .html to imdbID of the film for example something like AA0000001.html, then this will be file in my directory that it would link to, but not sure how I would do that

Comment: Is the linked page part of your app too?  If so, you'll want to use a `<router-link>` instead and it won't be a link to another page, but to another route (In a single page app, there's only the one page, index.html, but routes give the illusion of more).  If not, you can put the pages in the `public` directory.  This would be kind of uncommon but you might have a reason for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the created method as follows.

```
created() {
    var vm = this
    axios.get('https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Harry+Potter&apikey=a9018efb')
      .then(function(response) {
        vm.movies = response.data.Search;
        vm.movies.forEach(function(m){
            m.movieUrl = m.url + '.html';
        });
      })
  },
```

Modify the anchor tag as follows.
`<a :href="movie.movieUrl" class="btn btn-primary">`View Movie //This is where I'm wanting the variable to go